# Is it possible to use Cloudflare DNS to create a subdomain?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

Let's say I have the domain `example.com`, can I then use the Cloudflare DNS tool to map `static.example.com` to `example.com/static`?

I tried adding a `CNAME` entry, but I couldn't use slashes in the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use Cloudflare to create a DNS entry for your subdomain. The problem is that you can only point a `CNAME` record to another domain, not a URL.

You should however be able to configure the redirection from your subdomain on your web server.

**Update**: Curiosity compelled me to have a go at setting up a Cloudflare Page Rule for forwarding a subdomain to a URL and it works well. This feature does exactly what you are looking for.

Remember to create a `CNAME` entry for the subdomain you want to redirect, pointing to your domain root, and make sure that it is orange-clouded so it is processed by Cloudflare. Also remember that the DNS change may take a while to propagate.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. My problem is I'm using Github Pages as web server so I don't think I will be able to configure the redirection.

Comment: I haven't really played with this myself, but I think Cloudflare page rules might be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, you can set-up Forwarding in Page Rules which is likely what you're after: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-#redirects